# C++ gaussian output pixel

Tags: c++, gaussian

I need to construct a gaussian filter using C++. I am successfully getting my pixels from the image and constructing both grids; the one with 1 in the center and the one with one in the corner, my problem is I don't quit understand the gaussian equation! what should I put in the pixel that I should put in the output Image?? What should I put in else? Should I sum all the pixels from the modified grid (The one with 1 in the corner) or what?

```
for ( int r = 0; r < rowCt; r++ ) 
    {
      for ( int c = 0; c < colCt; c++ ) 
      {
        getPixel ( r, c, onePix );// geting pixel from the Img
        int index = getIndex(r,c);// change colomns and rows to one dimentional array

        if(c <= (f/2) || c >= colCt-((f/2)-1)-1 || r >= rowCt-((r/2)-1)-1 || r <= ((r/2)-1)) 
          onePix = 0;// black if in the border
        else
        {
          .... // ??

          }
          outIm.setPixel ( r, c, outPut_Pixel);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: There are actually two parts to your problem. The first is how to do a two-dimensional convolution, second is how to use the Gaussian formula to generate the coefficients for the convolution.

Comment: I am doing the two-dimensional convolution correctly, but what I'm missing is what to put in the output Image? do I have to put the result of this equation for mask of size 7, for instance =  h[i,j]=1/1115 * f[i,g] * g[i,j] ... Please can you explain what is f[i,g] here ? and what is g[i,j]

Comment: The code you posted isn't doing a convolution though. If it were there'd be another pair of loops.